# iOS localization for country specific region/language

Tags: ios, localization

I'm developing an iOS app with localizations for different languages. For example lt.lproj, et.lproj, lv.lproj directories. And now I need to create translation files for specific region so created directories lt-RU.lproj, et-RU.lproj and lv-RU.lproj (Xcode named automatically). Everything working as expected, but when trying to upload an update I get an email warning

```
Unrecognized Locale -
The directory located at ( 'Payload/.../lt-RU.lproj' ) has an 
unrecognized locale name. Refer to the Language and Locale Designations 
guide for more information on naming your language-specific 
directories.

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application 
Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.
```

I have read apple Internationalization and Localization Guide and don't understand whats wrong in my language-specific directory names. May be use underscore separator?

Answer (score 0):

My question was little bit wrong, because I need to change language not region for different countries. My project contains 3 targets for different counties so to add Russian translations I decided to create 3 directories containing ru.lproj and target needed app.